# How do I write jasmine-karma test cases for public static methods?

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am writing jasmine-karma test cases for a service where the methods are public static in nature. How ever I cannot access them or write test cases for them in the spec.ts file. Could anyone show me how?

This is my method in app.service.ts

```
public static getModifiedDate(dateVal: any): string {
    if ('' === dateVal) {
      return null;
    }
    const year = dateVal.substring(
      dateVal.lastIndexOf('/') + 1,
      dateVal.length
    );
    const month = dateVal.substring(0, dateVal.indexOf('/'));
    const date = dateVal.substring(
      dateVal.indexOf('/') + 1,
      dateVal.lastIndexOf('/')
    );
    return year + '-' + month + '-' + date;
  }
```

In the spec.ts file I cannot write the test cases for this function as I tried,

```
describe('AppService', () => {
  let service: AppService;
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [RestClientService, AppService]
    });
    service = TestBed.get(AppService);
  }));

  it('getModifieddate should return date in the expected format', () => {
    const date = service.getModifiedDate('04/20/2017');
    expect(date).toEqual('2017-04-20');
  }); 
});
```

It is showing error as getModifiedDate is a public static method.
What is the correct way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should invoke the static method in a static way: `AppService.getModifiedDate`. The test could be simplified as follows:

```
describe('AppService', () => {
  it('getModifieddate should return date in the expected format', () => {
    const date = AppService.getModifiedDate('04/20/2017');
    expect(date).toEqual('2017-04-20');
  }); 
});
```

Comment: It actually works!! thank you so much for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things you can give it a try, here are those:

- > ```
  > it('getModifieddate should return date in the expected format', () => {
  >     const date = (service as any).getModifiedDate('04/20/2017');
  >     expect(date).toEqual('2017-04-20');
  >   });
  > ```
- > ```
  > it('getModifieddate should return date in the expected format', () => {
  >     spyOn(service as any, 'getModifiedDate').and.callFake(() => {return '2017-04-20'; });
  >     const date = (service as any).getModifiedDate('04/20/2017');
  >     expect(date).toEqual('2017-04-20');
  >   });
  > ```
- > ```
  > it('getModifieddate should return date in the expected format', () => {
  >     const date = AppService.getModifiedDate('04/20/2017');
  >     expect(date).toEqual('2017-04-20');
  >   });
  > ```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you have any query.